# What do you call the act of doing something to win political points for the next election rather than useful things like enacting policies?

Tags: word-request

Politicians do this often, they smear people over and over again instead of discussing politics. In parliament, instead of discussing about policies, they sometimes waste time by making personal attacks, pointing little misdemeanors (like eating a snack in the parliament room), commenting on unproven allegations, etc. What is it called? Politicians often do this.

Comment: [point out///discuss policies, not about] I don't see how this is specifically something politicians do. Many do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is "[playing politics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/play%20politics)"--where politicians do things that aren't necessarily relevant to their constituents in order to benefit themselves or harm their opponents in the realm of public opinion.

It can be contrasted with enacting *policy*, which would have an impact on the public at large.

Comment: playing politics does not include the activities the OP has pointed out.

Comment: @Lambie Playing politics can absolutely include personal attacks, attacking another politician's conduct or attempting to make hay of unproven allegations in order to secure a political advantage. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Lip service can be a form of playing politics, but so can these negative things. Playing politics is about acting with personal political interests in mind instead of principles. It can take the form of insincere flattery or insincere attacks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Both flattery and attacks are components that can fall under the umbrella of playing politics. Either behavior is sufficient to merit a description of "playing politics," but neither is necessary.